# Compile Python extension module at runtime

Tags: python

Say I have a Python function that generates and returns, as a string, the C code for an extension module. Now I want, at runtime, to compile this C code into a `.so`/`.pyd` extension module so that I can import it.

How can I do this?

It seems that one should be able to use `setuptools` or `distutils` for this purpose since `setup.py` is itself just a normal Python script. However, these packages do a lot of extra stuff which is related to installation, dependency checking, and so on. Are there any direct API hooks which would allow me to simply compile a single extension module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found relevant code in the [PyStan](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan) project,
specifically, in the [`pystan.model`](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/blob/develop/pystan/model.py) module, which does essentially exactly what I need. I'll put a code fragment here for posterity. The below even handles Cython extensions, but it could be easily adapted to remove the Cython dependency if you don't need it.

```
from distutils.core import Extension

import Cython
from Cython.Build.Inline import _get_build_extension
from Cython.Build.Dependencies import cythonize

# you can add include_dirs= and extra_compile_args= here
extension = Extension(name='mymodule', language='c++', sources=[srcfile])

build_extension = _get_build_extension()
build_extension.extensions = cythonize([extension],
                                       include_path=[],
                                       quiet=False)
build_extension.build_temp = os.path.dirname(srcfile)
build_extension.build_lib = build_dir  # where you want the output

build_extension.run()
```

After compiling, you can load the module by putting it into the path (or adding its path to `sys.path`) and calling `importlib.import_module()`.

Comment: Friendly request from a stranger, how exactly would you do this without the cython dependency? Are we talking `subprocess` and `gcc`?

Comment: @Torxed I don't know, I haven't looked into it since I needed it for Cython extensions. The `cythonize` part you can simply skip, so all you'd need to figure out is what `_get_build_extension` does. My guess would be that you can replace `build_extension` with `extension` in the above code, but I haven't tried. You definitely don't have to go as low-level as `subprocess` and `gcc`, nor should you since it's not portable.